# Email notification when disk drive reaches a certain percentage? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'd love to be able to monitor my disk drives automatically with email notifications. I'm using Laravel (and therefore it should be possible to schedule a task to check) this but I'm unsure how to go about checking the available disk size through Laravel/PHP code. Any ideas?

I did find this article (but it's not strictly what I want as it uses shell directly to send emails and I want a laravel scheduled task to send the emails whenever it finds the disk drive at a specified percentage): https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's [disk_total_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php) and [disk_free_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way I would do this is, at first, prepare a function to check for disk space.

```
function spaceLimit($limitPercent) {
    $drive = "/";
    $space = (disk_free_space($drive) / disk_total_space($drive)) * 100;
    return $limitPercent < $space;
}
```

Then, send an email after checking at a specific internal (in file `app/Console/Kernel.php`).

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // Ensure queue:work is running
    $schedule->call(function() {
        // 90% and more space used
        if (spaceLimit(90)) {
            Mail::to('admin@me.com')->send(/* Some Mailable Class here */);
        }
    })->everyFiveMinutes(); // Change interval here
}
```

Of course, the `spaceLimit` function can be stored in the same file, or in another, or wherever you want.
Also, you can imagine having an [Event class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events) to easily handle other kinds of notifications later (such as SMS, Push Notification, whatever..).

Don't forget you will need to configure a cron to execute your tasks. Crontab :

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And, if your emails are in a queue, you will also need to start the queue :

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [disk_free_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) and  [disk_total_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)

```
<?php
   define('MAX_LIMIT', 90);

   $diskRoot = "/"; // for unix/linux in case of windows use "C:" / "D:"

   $perSpace = (disk_free_space($diskRoot) / disk_total_space($diskRoot)) * 100;
   if(MAX_LIMIT < $perSpace) {
       //send email from here
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [disk_free_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) it Returns available space on filesystem or disk partition :

```
<?php
  // $df contains the number of bytes available on "/"
  $df = disk_free_space("/");

  // On Windows:
  $df_c = disk_free_space("C:");
  $df_d = disk_free_space("D:");
?>
```

If you want to check total space of your disk, then use [disk_total_space()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)

```
<?php
  // $ds contains the total number of bytes available on "/"
  $ds = disk_total_space("/");

  // On Windows:
  $ds = disk_total_space("C:");
  $ds = disk_total_space("D:"); 
?>
```